# How to use async service in Spring interceptor?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets

I would like to log HTTP request / response data in my own implementation  of `HandlerInterceptor` and save data with `@Async` annotated method (to avoid blocking the main thread).

Interceptor is called properly but when an exception occures, in interceptor get correctly 500 Internal Server Error `HttpServletResponse`, but in `@Async` method get HTTP status 200 OK.

```
public class LoggingInterceptor implements AsyncHandlerInterceptor {

  private static Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(LoggingInterceptor.class);

  private final AsyncLogRequestInfoSaver saver;

  public LoggingInterceptor(final AsyncLogRequestInfoSaver saver) {
    this.saver = saver;
  }

  @Override
  public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {

    LOGGER.debug("HTTP status code: {}", response.getStatus()); // Here I got HTTP 500
    this.saver.save(request, response);

  }
}
```

Async method:

```
@Service
public class AsyncLogRequestInfoSaver {
    
      @Async
    public void save(final HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws JsonProcessingException {
    
        LOGGER.debug("HTTP status code: {}", response.getStatus()); // Here I got HTTP 200
    
    }
    
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Servlet containers often pool `HttServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` objects. By the time `save` runs, the `HttpServletResponse` might be in use in for another request. In general, it's not safe to use them this way.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thank you. What is the safe way how to achieve it?

Comment: Capture what you need from those objects and only use that.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Do I understand correctly to grab information from HttpServletRequest object to send them to my `Async` service and do not rely to whole `HttpServletRequest `? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, for eg. pass only the status, not the whole response.